# Using FitNesse with .Net across multiple servers

Tags: automated-testing, fitnesse, dot-net

My previous work involved writing embedded Linux code.  We used a couple of the embedded devices in a test harness, a Linux PC and the Windows Perforce repository.  The Linux PC ran an instance of FitNesse and used (among other things) the [CommandLineFixture](http://fit.c2.com/wiki.cgi?CommandLineFixture) to cross-compile the latest binaries, deploy them to the target, and then execute the tests.

My current project involved the Microsoft stack, developing web services.  I would like to be able to use FitNesse to test out this system, but I'm at a loss as to where to start.  The Linux system meant all that `bash` scripting goodness, so building (`make`), deployment (`ssh` or `scp`) and collating results (`scp`) were all easy.

I'm assuming I can use a similar chain under Windows-only:

- `MSBuild` for building
- `putty` for deployment / collating results

but deployment of IIS web services seems more complex than just copying files.

Do you have any pointers?

Comment: Peter, if you are testing web services in the .net stack, why don't you consider just using the mstest unit testing infrastructure as a client calling the web services. I know that you don't get fit as a front end, but it can solve a lot of the other issues. You could consider using spcflow in leiu of fit.

Comment: @Bruce McLeod: Thanks for your thoughts!  I have been investigating specflow, too, so thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: What's your general deployment strategy? Do you have Dev, QA, and production environments? And yes, deployment to IIS is complicated. But it IS doable, via msbuild. Google around for msbuild/iis deployment options and you'll find info on how to do it.

Comment: @StephenGross: "Dev" environment tends to be developer local.  Other than that, yes, we have QA and production.  I'll have more of a poke. This is starting to become a bigger issue.

Comment: @PeterK. In our case, we use Local, Dev, QA, and Production. Local is indeed possible, but obviously you have to configure it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using SpecFlow, C#, NUnit and WebDriver to handle much of this.  I write all of my tests within Visual Studio and use PowerShell to check source out, compile and start the tests to check my site and services.  This gives it a nice framework feel, and once the updated Build System is complete I can add my tests into the build system, my PowerShell commands are written as functions so it will be easier to run the tests.  I used Fitnesse before and had some success with it, but had problems migrating the tests across servers, even using REST I had issues and a lot of scripts that I really didn't need for what I was doing.  SpecFlow and NUnit gave me the ability to reuse more of my scripts than Fitnesse did, mostly for being able to direct my tests to different machines which I found difficult to do in Fitnesse and easy to do in SpecFlow and NUnit.

Comment: Apologies it's taken so long to give you the tick!  I eventually went with something not unlike what you describe, which was easier than Fitnesse in an MS environment.